# Solve equations with one variable

Tags: equation-solving

I have some equations, like the one below.

```
 eq6 = -1.94178*10^24 H (1 + 
  0.00391389 Te) Te^0.5 - (3.2*10^-9 ((3.47471*10^26 Te^(7/
          2) (3.525 + 0.0000425559 Te^3))/(0.5814 + 
       0.000109998 Te^3 + 
       1.30798*10^-10 Te^6) + (1.75417*10^23 Ti^(7/2) (2.645 + 
         2.81978*10^-10 Ti^3))/(0.677 + 3.8067*10^-10 Ti^3 + 
       1.98779*10^-20 Ti^6)))/H + 
   7.68349*10^40 H ((5.41*10^-15 E^(-148/Ti))/
   Ti^(3/2) + (2.00122*10^-10 E^(-((53.124 (1 - (-0.059357 Ti + 
                0.0010404 Ti^2 - 9.1653*10^-6 Ti^3)/(1 + 
                0.20165 Ti + 0.0027621 Ti^2 + 
                9.8305*10^-7 Ti^3))^(1/3))/Ti^(1/3))))/(Ti^(2/
        3) (1 - (-0.059357 Ti + 0.0010404 Ti^2 - 
           9.1653*10^-6 Ti^3)/(1 + 0.20165 Ti + 0.0027621 Ti^2 + 
           9.8305*10^-7 Ti^3))^(5/6)));
```

i can easily solve and plot them with Solve.

```
     f6 = H /. Solve[eq6 == 0, H] // Simplify;
     c = {0.5, 1, 1.5};


ContourPlot[f6[[2]], {Ti, 0, 1000}, {Te, 0, 105}, 
Exclusions -> "Singularities", 
Contours -> c,(*ColorFunction\[Rule]"IslandColors",*)
ContourShading -> None, PlotPoints -> 100, 
FrameLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(i\)]\)", 
FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Times"], 
Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(e\)]\)", FontSize -> 12, 
FontFamily -> "Times"]}, 
LabelStyle -> {Directive[Black, Bold], (FontSize -> 12), 
FontFamily -> "Times"}, ContourLabels -> Automatic, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 1000}, {0, 105}}]
```

this gives the desired plot.

[image]

my problem is when I change the equation to the following, it cannot be solved.

for example:

```
eq1=-1.94178*10^24 H (1 + 0.00391389 Te) Te^0.5 - (
2.11997*10^14 (1 + 0.00488542 Te) Te)/H - (
3.2*10^-9 ((
3.47471*10^26 Te^(7/2) (3.525 + (4.25559*10^-9 Te^3)/H^2))/(
0.5814 + (1.09998*10^-8 Te^3)/H^2 + (1.30798*10^-18 Te^6)/H^4) + (
1.75417*10^23 Ti^(7/2) (2.645 + (2.81978*10^-14 Ti^3)/H^2))/(
0.677 + (3.8067*10^-14 Ti^3)/H^2 + (1.98779*10^-28 Ti^6)/
 H^4)))/H + (
7.68349*10^40 H (8/3 (5.84303*10^-6 + (131.462 H)/Te^(3/2)) + 
64/9 (5.84303*10^-6 + (131.462 H)/Te^(3/2))^2) ((
5.41*10^-15 E^(-148/Ti))/Ti^(3/2) + (
2.00122*10^-10 E^(-((
  53.124 (1 - (-0.059357 Ti + 0.0010404 Ti^2 - 
      9.1653*10^-6 Ti^3)/(
     1 + 0.20165 Ti + 0.0027621 Ti^2 + 9.8305*10^-7 Ti^3))^(1/3))/
  Ti^(1/3))))/(
Ti^(2/3) (1 - (-0.059357 Ti + 0.0010404 Ti^2 - 
    9.1653*10^-6 Ti^3)/(
   1 + 0.20165 Ti + 0.0027621 Ti^2 + 9.8305*10^-7 Ti^3))^(
 5/6))))/(
 1 + 104/27 (5.84303*10^-6 + (131.462 H)/Te^(3/2)) + 
  64/9 (5.84303*10^-6 + (131.462 H)/Te^(3/2))^2)
```

How can i solve this and then plot?

Comment: I cannot see the symbol of equality (==),  but only `Set` (=) i.e. you define expressions as `eq1` and `eq2`, but there is no equation. Nonetheless, even if you change `=` into `==` and `eq1` and `eq2` into `0` then there are `3` unknowns and only `2` equations, and so there will be infinitely many solutions, not a few of them.

Comment: @ Artes I think i did not explain well i will edit the question. my problem is with solving . they should be solved seperately, they are not coupled.